# Java で String への変換時にエラー: 不適合な型；java.lang.StringをStringに変換できません

Tags: java

Javaの参考書にて数値を文字列化する演習をしていたのですが、例として載っているコードをコンパイルしようとしたところ、下記の部分に対してエラーが表示されました。
Javaに詳しい方、教えていただけると幸いです。

**該当箇所:**

```
s = Integer.toString(i , 2);
s = integer.toString(i , 16);
```

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
不適合な型；java.lang.StringをStringに変換できません
```

**ソースコード:**

```
class String {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String s ;      
        int i = 45;

        s = Integer.toString(i , 2);
        System.out.println(s);
    
        s = Integer.toString(i , 16);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```java
> class String {
>       public static void main(String args[]) {
>           String s ;
> ```

この `s` は、質問者さんが作った `String` クラスのインスタンスになってます。Java標準の`String`ではなく。

自作の`String`の名前を変えるか、`s` の宣言を`java.lang.String s;`にしましょう。

Answer (score 0):

質問文中のコードでは、 `String` という名前でクラスを作っていますが、Java組み込みの [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/11/docs/api/index.html) と名前が被っているので想定と異なる状態になっています(参考: [6.4.1. Shadowing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1))。

参照されているサンプルコードでは別の名前になっていると思いますので、1行目の `String` をそちらと同じ名前に書き換えてみてください。

---

わかりやすいように(名前が被らないように)、質問文中のコードを書き換えると次のような感じになります。

```java
class MyString {
    public static void main(MyString args[]) {
        MyString s ;      
        int i = 45;

        s = Integer.toString(i , 2);
        System.out.println(s);
    
        s = Integer.toString(i , 16);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

`String` 型である `Integer.toString()` の戻り値を、 `MyString` 型の `s` に代入しようとしているので

> エラー: 不適合な型: StringをMyStringに変換できません

というコンパイルエラーになります。